# What traversal is more probable to keep tree balanced

Tags: algorithm, conways-game-of-life, kdtree

I am trying to simulate Conway's game of life. I am representing the 'Live cells' as a coordinate vector (x, y). The initial live cells are inserted into a kd tree (k=2) such that it is perfectly balanced. If a node doesn't exist in the tree, it is assumed to be dead.

The simulation is an array of trees with generation i at `trees[i]`. When transitioning from `tree[i-1]` to `tree[i]`, I traverse `tree[i-1]` and check each node and its neighbors whether they're alive or not. If a node is alive, it gets inserted into `tree[i]`.

What is the best way to traverse the tree such that if we start with `tree[0]` being perfectly balanced, we have the highest probability that the upcoming generations will be 'most balanced'?

Comment: Are you doing Theta(n) lookups in the kd-tree each generation? If so, you could just rebuild the tree from scratch every few generations without increasing the overall cost too much.

Comment: If it pays to completely rebuild the 2-d tree rather often, does that imply that the advantage over a linked list of lexicographically sorted (x,y) pairs is not so great? (Disclosure: I have a Game of Life implementation based on such a linked list.)

Comment: It's not clear what a k-d tree is doing for you, beyond membership tests (i.e. to see if a cell is alive or dead). Why not just maintain a separate bit array for those membership tests?

Comment: Traversing the k-d tree gives all cells that are currently alive, and when moving to the next generation, only these and their neighbors need to be looked at. No double-loop `for (x=...) for (y=...)` is needed.